# How to restore the content of .android folder?

Tags: android, react-native, android-app-bundle

I am working for a `React-Native` project and using `MAC`.

I have accidentally deleted `.android` folder. Then I completely deleted `Android Studio` and installed once again. Now, `.android` folder is created automatically, But still some content seems missing like `keystore` files. Due to to this I am unable to create `Signed Bundles`.

Is there any way to have `keystore` files inside `.android` folder?

By the way I have a copy of `keystore` files inside `<root>/android/app/` location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.android folder is auto-generated. That means that you should not store anything that is not autogenerated in it(especially keystore files). It should not be subjected to version control also.

The official and correct way to have it as you want - is to have a separate not autogenerated android folder that can be put under version control. I can see that you have it like that already which is good.

To build your signed bundles and apk files you should set up a correct path to your keystore(from /android/app/) in your build.gradle file in the signing config section - [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android) is the official info about how to do it.

About how to restore .android content - if you had no version control there or any other snapshot - you cannot restore it. You can tweak its content a bit via the general project/ide settings but that is it.

Answer (score -1):

I'm no expert but.

It seems that it didn't uninstall the software entirely.

**Try**

- Updating the Android Studio
- Or Reinstall it again
- Or [Install the Nightly Build/Developer Release](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview) I reckon that there is no builds for mac.